# what are the challenges of mobility on top of blockchains and smart contracts, and why?

Tags: contract-development, mobile-wallet

I want to develop mobile smart contracts so my question is basically related to mobility regarding blockchain and smart contracts.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is that you want to develop a **mobile distributed application** (or mobile dApp).

The main challenge is the way your dApp will be able to interact with:

- an ETH wallet (so the user can sign transactions)
- an ethereum node, because these nodes are actually executing the smart contract

[Status IM](https://status.im/) is working on a platform to help overcome these challenges and enable the development of **mobile dApps**. And most certainly there are others who are working to solve these issues, but you'll have to search for them because I don't know about them.